# when tried to edit .bashrc file The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: files, environment-variables

When i tried to edit .bashrc file I am getting the above error how to solve this.
when i gave

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/vijay/usr/bin:PATH:/bin
```

is displayed
Steps in detail would help

Answer (score 3):

When you typed the changes to `~/.bashrc` you omitted a `$`. Re-edit your `~/.bashrc` with:

```
/usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc
```

Find the line:

```
PATH=/home/vijay/usr/bin:PATH:/bin
```

and change it to:

```
PATH=/home/vijay/usr/bin:$PATH:/bin  
-------------------------^
```